# Grep opposite option of "-o" (Not -v)

Tags: grep, string

I'd like to print only the part of string that doesn't match. Is there an opposite option of `grep -o`? Not `grep -v` because it ignores the string containing pattern completely.

Lets say I have:

```
setenv var   "/home/user/dir/subdir/case"
setenv path  "/home/user/dir"
```

I need to only return `subdir/case` but I cannot find an easy way to do it with `grep`.

If `grep -o` returns only part of string that matches, is there a negative option for this that only returns part of string that doesn't match?

Comment: In that example where you want `subdir/case` output, what would you use for your match?

Comment: Re: "_`I need to only return subdir/case`_"- `grep -o 'subdir/case'`. your question is not clear enough, please [edit] and say what you want match in given example other than `subdir/case` that then you need `subdir/case` as result.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` or Perl you can remove a part of the line that matches a pattern and print the remaining line. Assuming your example data is in `file.txt`:

```
$ sed -ne 's/^setenv var *//p' < file.txt 
"/home/user/dir/subdir/case"
```

What you ask about getting just `subdir/case` actually requires removing two parts, since there's also the ending quote. It's easier to just use a capture group to get a part from the middle. Here, the `(.*)` part tells `sed` to store the part of the string that fits at this point, and `\1` in the replacement part tells to replace everything that matched with it. The print (`p`) command is conditional on the substitution (`s///`) matching here. I use `,` as the separator since `/` appears in the pattern itself, but you could use any character.

```
$ sed -nEe 's,^setenv var *"/home/user/dir/(.*)".*,\1,p' < file.txt 
subdir/case
```

or in Perl, without replacing anything, but just printing the captured part on a match:

```
$ perl -lne 'print $1 if m,^setenv var *"/home/user/dir/(.*)",' < file.txt 
subdir/case
```

Both of the above print nothing for lines that don't match the pattern.

If you want to print those too, in full, make the printing unconditional (note the semicolon before `p`):

```
$ sed -nEe 's,^setenv var *"/home/user/dir/(.*)",\1,; p' < file.txt 
subdir/case
setenv path  "/home/user/dir"
```

or

```
$ perl -lne 's,^setenv var *"/home/user/dir/(.*)",$1,; print' < file.txt
subdir/case
setenv path  "/home/user/dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [GNU grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) with [`lookbehind assertion` and `lookahead assertion`](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC19):

```bsh
# return what doesn't match 'dir/' at the end of the line
# and doesn't match the final double quote '"'
$ grep -Po '(?<=dir/).*(?="$)' file
subdir/case
```

This assumes the 'negative' pattern `dir/` before `subdir/case`. If the pattern is the full directory:

```bsh
grep -Po '(?<="/home/user/dir/).*(?="$)' file
```